# Generic fast coded PHP MySQL dynamic insert/update query creating table/fields named as variables if doesnt exists

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a way to make MySQL insert/update queries more dynamic and fast to code since sometimes one just need another field in a form (when for example **prototyping** an application). This might be a dumb question.

My idea is to make an insert or update if ids match, and if table/fields doesn't exists create it with one function dynamically.

```
<?php 
// $l is set with some db-login stuff

// creates and inserts
$f[] = nf(1,'this_id_x'); // this_id_* could be a prefix for ids
$f[] = nf('value yep',$fieldname_is_this2)
$tbl_name = "it_didnt_exist";
nyakilian_fiq($l, $tbl_name, $f);
// Done!


//This would do an update on above
$fieldname_is_this2 = "this is now updated";
$f[] = nf(1,'this_id_x'); 
$f[] = nf($fieldname_is_this2); // the function takes the variable name as field name
$tbl_name = "it_didnt_exist";
nyakilian_fiq($l, $tbl_name, $f);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this function with success. It doesn't add a column but that is against the structure of my MVC framework. Try something like this:

```
public function save(DatabaseConnection &$db)
{
    $properties = get_object_vars($this);
    $table = $this->getTableName();
    // $cols = array();
    // $values = array();
    foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
        $cols[] = "`$key`";
        $values[] = '"'.$value.'"';
        if ($value != NULL) {
            $updateCols[] = "`$key`".' = "'.$value.'"';
        }
    }

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(", ", $cols).') VALUES ('.implode(", ",  $values).') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '.implode(", ", $updateCols);

    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    var_dump($stmnt);
    if ($stmnt->execute($values)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

I have a model abstract class that I extend with a child class for each database table. This function sits in the model abstract. Each child class contains a public property [so I can use PDO::fetchObject()] that corresponds to a column name in the table. If I need to create the table on the fly, I add a function to the child class to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite unusable approach.

You are trying to mix into one single function (not even a class(!) a functionality that fits for a decent framework. That's just impossible (or unusable for some parts).
Yet it resembles major frameworks' Models in many aspects.

So, I could give just some recommendations

- Do not create tables dynamically. Data structure is a backbone of the application and have to be solid.
- do not take too much considerations (like "If an ID is passed"). it will tie your hands for whatever more complex case
- take a look at some major frameworks - it seems your wishes are already fulfilled with their codegeneration feature (an ugliest thing that ever existed on the Erath in my private opinion). They're working pretty the same way you're talking about: you have to only define a *Model* and [the rest is done by framework's methods](http://www.yiiframework.com/tour/)

Comment: Thanks your answer was indeed informative and brought new light. But I'm still a little keen on knowing how to make such a function (or better - class). I believe it can be useful for prototyping. Maybe prototyping could then better be made with pen and paper leaving the database stuff for structured work later in the process. Perhaps anyone could recommend a framework for "fast dynamic" queries, preferably lightweight and easily implemented for this specifically? (If it's a bit off topic and suits better in another so-question let me know.)